# Replace a string in mustache template

Tags: mustache

I have a mustache code to generate the output in the below format.

[{{url}}]

here url comes like "http://test.it.corp.com", I would like to replace the "http" with "external". Is it possible through mustache. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Since the [the manual](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) doesn't mention any seemingly possible way to modify tags this is probably not possible using  Mustache itself.

Answer (score 3):

After so much research found there is no way to do this in mustache, I did it in java and sent the string to mustache.